# Golang regex cant match byte 10

Tags: regex, go, byte, newline

Try the following:

```
func main(){
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(.)`)
    for i := 0; i < 255; i++{
        d := []byte{byte(i)}
        all := r.FindAll(d, -1)
        fmt.Println(all)
    }
}
```

The wildcard cannot match byte 10 (ie the new line character). Looks like a bug. I suppose regex was never really meant to work with []byte, but golang offers the []byte functions, so this is kind of an oversight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell it to match against new lines .. by specifying the `s` flag:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)(.)`)
```

Try it in the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/MK-UECa9AV

The `s` flag tells the parser to let `.` match a new line.